# Can't get Edittext values to show in new activity?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-edittext, spinner

kinda of a noob at this. I'm Having a little trouble getting some of my values from the edit text to transfer into a new activity. I'm Trying to set it up to where the chosen spinner item will place it into the right text view. I'm not getting a force close but it is just not putting the user values into the text view. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

MAIN ACTIVITY

```
public class RoofingClaculatorActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener,           android.view.View.OnClickListener {

EditText hFeetInput;
EditText hInchesInput;
EditText wFeetInput;
EditText wInchesInput;
Spinner slopeSpinner;
Button save;
int pos;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.savedata);
    save.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    EditText hFeetInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.hFeetInput);
    EditText hInchesInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.hInchesInput);
    EditText wFeetInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.wFeetInput);
    EditText wInchesInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.wInchesInput);

    String hFeet = hFeetInput.getText().toString();
    String hInches = hInchesInput.getText().toString();
    String wFeet = wFeetInput.getText().toString();
    String wInches = wInchesInput.getText().toString();

    Double HFEET = Double.parseDouble(hFeet);
    Double HINCHES = Double.parseDouble(hInches);
    Double WFEET = Double.parseDouble(wFeet);
    Double WINCHES = Double.parseDouble(wInches);

    Intent i = new Intent(this, DisplayResults.class);
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putDouble("hFeetInput", HFEET);
    b.putDouble("hInchesInput", HINCHES);
    b.putDouble("wFeetInput", WFEET);
    b.putDouble("wInchesInput", WINCHES);

    i.putExtras(b);
    startActivity(i);
}

public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

SECOND ACTIVITY

```
public class DisplayResults extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnItemSelectedListener {
static Double aHInches;
static Double aWInches;
static Double aHFeet;
static Double aWFeet;
private static double Squared = 0;
private static double Inches = 0;   
static String aSquared= Double.toString(Squared);
static String addedInches=Double.toString(Inches);;;
static TextView a_feet;
static TextView b_feet;
static TextView a_Inches;
static TextView b_Inches;
int pos;
Spinner slopeSpinner;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.displayresult);
    initialize();

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.array.slopeArray, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    slopeSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.slopeSpinner);




    Bundle gotData = getIntent().getExtras();
    aHFeet = gotData.getDouble("hFeetInput");
    aHInches = gotData.getDouble("hInchesInput");
    aWFeet = gotData.getDouble("wFeetInput");
    aWInches = gotData.getDouble("wInchesInput");
    Inches = aHInches + aWInches;
    Squared = aHFeet * aWFeet / 100;
    aSquared = Double.toString(Squared);
    addedInches = Double.toString(Inches);

}



private void initialize() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    a_feet = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.aHeight);
    b_feet = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bHeight);
    a_Inches = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.aInches);
    b_Inches = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bInches);

}

public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    slopeSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    slopeSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    pos = slopeSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition();

    if(pos == 0){
        a_feet.setText(aSquared);
        a_Inches.setText(addedInches);
    }else if (pos == 1){
        b_feet.setText(aSquared);
        b_Inches.setText(addedInches);
    }
}

public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

 }
```

Again any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What does your LogCat print?

Comment: it doesn't say anything im not getting any type of force close or anything here is what it says right now.  12-20 22:06:49.787: I/Choreographer(2536): Skipped 70 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

Comment: @JoelRolon there was a suggested answer(that is now gone) about changing your `setText()` methods to be `setText(""+yourValue);` I was wondering if you saw it and tried it out?

Comment: yes I saw it and tried it but I'm still getting the same results.

Comment: Woops, I misread, aSquared is a String anyways. Have you tried replacing the `Bundle` and working directly with the Intent `putExtra()` and `getDoubleExtra()` methods?

Comment: use can use. savedInstanceState.getIntent().getExtra(). here the savedInstancedState is your Bundle Of onCreate()

Comment: did you checked the values before sending.

Comment: have you tried intent.putExtra("hFeetInput", HFEET); instead of passing the bundle?

Comment: ill try all of these suggestions and see how it goes thank you.

Comment: Can you please do one thing. Instead of putting your values in Bundle, put it in Intent i; like i.putExtra("key",value);

Answer (score 0):

Write below code into `onItemSelected()` method of `DisplayResults.java` file, it will solve your problem and if you have any query regarding that then tell me.

```
if (pos == 0){
    a_feet.setText("Squared is:- " + aSquared);
    a_Inches.setText("Added Inches is:- " +addedInches);
} else if (pos == 1){
    b_feet.setText("Squared is:- " + aSquared);
    b_Inches.setText("Added Inches is:- " + addedInches);
}
```